# Jquery File Upload - Query Select Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery File Upload it seems to be a good plugin, but I have a huge problem for the select statement in the query.
The column "description" in the database contains the number 5, but unfortunately it does not work after so many attempts.

I also tried to change the session_id:`enter code here`

```
 protected function get_user_id() {
        @session_start();
        return session_id();
    }
```

with:

```
protected function get_user_id() {
        @session_start();
        return $_session['description'];
    }
```

I hope someone can have a solution, I read many forums but no seems there is never able.
Sorry fom my English
Many thanks in advance
Johnny

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);

        $cr='5';
        if ($reqMeth = 'GET') {
            $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `description`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('i', $cr);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description 
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->type = $type;
                $file->title = $title;
                $file->description = $description;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared $cr as string but passing it as integer. Could this be the problem?

```
    $cr='5'; /* <------------ string */
    if ($reqMeth = 'GET') {
        $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `description`=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('i', $cr); /* <---- integer passing */
```

Try passing $cr parameter as string. Also verify description is a varchar type field.

```
$query->bind_param('s', $cr);
```

If your description in the database is actually `integer` field, you might want to change the first line to

```
$cr= 5;
```

Probably worth a try.